# How to resolve pip install error between numpy==1.23.5 and numpy==1.24.2?

Tags: python

I am trying to pip install a requirements.txt file that has the following content.

[Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbn7d.png)

It produces the following error when it gets to the numpy.

[Numpy pip error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYHQz.png)

the relevant repository is https://github.com/joamats/mit-sepsis-tx.git

I've tried going through the suggested fixes but not sure on what loosening might do further down the line as I'm not sure which paritcular features are required from each package.

Is someone able to possibly explain what features might be neccessary from each package, why both are specified to start with and what might be done to resolve?

Comment: Why on earth does the requirements file have two DIFFERENT versions of numpy?!

Comment: This seems to be the code owner mistake of having same package with different versions of the requirements.txt file. Can't you just delete one of the two numpy version because one of them will never be used at runtime

Comment: "Is someone able to possibly explain what features might be neccessary from each package, why both are specified to start with and what might be done to resolve?" Possibly, the person responsible for creating the `requirements.txt` file. However, this is certainly a mistake anyway. Python's packaging system does not support parallel instlalations of different versions of the same library (since there is no way, in the language syntax, to specify which one to `import`).

Answer (score -1):

## Create a virtual environment

python -m venv myenv

## Activate the virtual environment (Windows)

myenv\Scripts\activate

## Activate the virtual environment (Linux/macOS)

source myenv/bin/activate
Then
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
Then
pip install numpy==1.24.2
Then
pip install numpy==1.23.5
Then
conda create -n myenv python=3.8 numpy=1.24.2
Then
conda activate myenv

Remember that the exact steps may vary depending on your specific project and requirements, but these general guidelines should help you resolve version conflicts when working with NumPy and other Python packages.

Comment: _pip install numpy==1.24.2 Then pip install numpy==1.23.5_ Surely that would just overwrite the 1.24.2 version?